# MacOS Mojave 10.14 cannot recognise Motu 828x audio interface

Tags: macos, audio, mojave

I am running on macOS Mojave 10.14. I installed the latest driver from Motu compatible with my Mac.

Unfortunately when plugging in my Motu 828x sound interface it is not recognized in *System Preferences > Sound > Output/Input*.

When I check in *System information > Hardware > USB > USB3*, the audio interface appears. If I try to open any DAW also there the interface does not appear.

So far I already tried:

- a reboot by pressing <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>
- delete some possible corrupted plist files and restart the computer
- uninstall and install the Motu drivers many times

However, nothing has worked!

Can someone please assist me in getting my Motu 828x audio interface working on my Mac?

Comment: There seem to be two versions of the driver, the newer one only works with macOS 10.15. Which one did you install?

Comment: Also, did you already contact Motu customer support? They might be in a better position to help you.

Comment: Is the device plugged in at boot? That's an essential for many interfaces; 'hot plugging' afterwards doesn't work.

Comment: @nohillside, I did contact the Motu technical service, but they have been totally helpless with the answers and above all they are not answering back since 3 weeks now. I double checked the software version of the drivers I installed, and they are correct. Thanks anyway for trying! If you have any further idea please let me know ;)

Comment: Did the audio interface work before installing the latest driver? Do you have access to another computer you could test it with? Did you use different cables to make sure that it's not a hardware issue?